# MySQL Server access

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose API server access the SQL server from request, the connection for the MySQL server is such.

```
    @mysql_connect(HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die('Could not connect to : ' . mysql_error());

    @mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME) or die( "<-----------------------Unable to select database------------------>");
```

is there a way to detect whether the connection is already opened? If it's opened then make a sql transaction.

Let's say while accessing table A, another API request call from outside come in and wanting to acess table B.

IS it possible to initiate an access to table B while table A operation still in progress.

In other word, don't wait access Table A to finish. As soon as access Table B come in then start it.

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jasonwhite I believe that concurrency is handled at the DBMS level, which, depending on the operation in question, already supports the possibility of two operations running at the same time. If for example, operation one were a *SELECT operation*, and operation two were an *INSERT operation* both could be executed at the same time. In fact, regardless of the operation types this would be possible, except if the tables were related via a foreign key constraint. This is because MySQL implements table-locking during operations, in which it locks a table while an operation is being executed on it, and then releases the table once that operation is completed.

Regarding checking if a connection already exists, you would need to implement a **singleton** method that would check if the connection already exists. If it does not, create it and return it; if it does, return the existing connection. This would look something like this:

```
function getConnection() {
    global $conn; //I do not recommend using globals, rather create a class for this
    if(is_null($conn)) {
         $conn = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die('Could not connect to : ' . mysql_error());    
         mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME) or die( "<-----------------------Unable to select database------------------>");
    }
    return $conn;        
}
```

AFAIK, you have no further control over whether one operation will wait for another during execution. My $0.02.

Comment: hi tash, someone suggest to me to have two tables, one table and another is a duplicate. this way it can help to split the read and write operation.   Is that true?

Comment: Also tash, the getconnection method, if connection is already opened then reuse it. Would that reduce the latency for the next operation?

Comment: @jason, Having two tables would, IMO, certainly reduce latency issues. But how would you keep the tables in sync? I think the overhead and increased complexity introduced by that setup would not be worth the effort. 

On your second comment, indeed it would reduce the latency as opening a connection comes with some overhead. But I think you would only really see the difference on 'high traffic' (hard to define) sites.

Comment: Tash, for argument sake, just say we have two tables, one is the original and the other is duplicate, how can we be sure read and write transaction happen at the same time to the 2 tables?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't think there is a way you could ever guarantee that.